# How to write a es6 onchange method using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a onchange function defined like below using typescript and react.

```
<Form>
    {({ field, form }: FieldProps) => (
        <Switch
          {...field}
          disabled={somecondition}
          checked={field.value === something}
          onChange={() => {
            if (field.value === somevalue) {
              form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, manual);
            } else {
              form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, automation);
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Form>
```

this works. but as you see from code above, the onchange method is defined there only. I want to write the function definition to another function and call it on onChange.

i have tried something like below,

```
 const handleChange = (field, form) => { //throws error: field has implicit type any and form has 
 //implicit type any
     if (field.value === somevalue) {
         form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, manual);
     } else {
         form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, automation);
     }
 }; 
 <Form>
    {({ field, form }: FieldProps) => (
        <Switch
          {...field}
          disabled={somecondition}
          checked={field.value === something}
          onChange={handleChange(field, form)} //error: type void is not assignable to type 
          //((event:changeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
        />
      )}
    </Form>
```

i see some errors as mentioned above in the code snippet. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Hover over the onChange on the <Switch> component. You will see its type then look at at the end then copy all lines after ":".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error where `field` and `form` both have implicit type `any` is thrown since you haven't defined the types for the parameters for your newly created function. To resolve the error, you will need to provide types to `handleChange()`. One approach is to use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to define the parameters' types:

```
type HandleChange = (field: FieldProps['field'], form: FieldProps['form']) => void

const handleChange: HandleChange = (field, form) => {
  if (field.value === somevalue) {
    form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, manual)
  } else {
    form.setFieldValue(SOURCE, automation)
  }
}
```

The error stating that `type void is not assignable to type (event:changeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void` is thrown since you're immediately invoking `handleChange()`:

```
<Switch
  {...field}
  disabled={somecondition}
  checked={field.value === something}
  onChange={handleChange(field, form)} // <-- handleChange() is invoked here
/>
```

As @JoshMerrian stated, an approach to resolving this error is to create a function which invokes `handleChange()`:

```
<Switch
  {...field}
  disabled={somecondition}
  checked={field.value === something}
  onChange={() => handleChange(field, form)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onChange={handleChange(field, form)}`, it should be `onChange={() => handleChange(field, form)}` Because what the onChange prop is looking for is a function not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the onChange prop.
You will see this.
[image: Type]

Then look at the its type after the ":". Copy that and put that as the type for your onChange method.